# how to load image from css file to go.picture in gojs

Tags: jquery, html, css, gojs

I have a situation where i need to provide image from CSS file to goJs go.picture method. not from cross origin.
how to pass it.

```
GO(go.Picture, {source: 'images/sample.png',
                 sourceRect: new go.Rect(117, 9, 88, 16),
                 alignment: new go.Spot(0.5, 0, 0, 15)
               }),
```

Here i want to pass source from CSS file by using class name or Id.
Is it possible...?

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating an `<img>` that has the CSS source you want, and then setting the `Picture.element` to that `img` instead.